# How to use $array[$i-1] when index is on 0

Tags: php, arrays, loops

I have this code that is - I take a users value, if it is in the array it will output that array value, the value after it, and the value before. They way I have done it works fine (im unsure if there is an easier way!), the only problem is - If the value is already indexed at 0, it can't -1 and it causes an error. What I would like it to do is if the user entered Monday, then the output would be - Sunday, Monday, Tuesday.

How would I do it so would out put the last value if the user DID enter Monday?

Here is my code -

```
<?php
         $user_input = $_POST ['user_input'];
         $user_input_lower = strtolower($user_input);

           $days= array(
            0 => 'Monday',
            1 => 'Tuesday',
            2 => 'Wednesday',
            3 => 'Thursday',
            4 => 'Friday',
            5 => 'Saturday',
            6 => 'Sunday'
            );

          for ($i=0; $i < 7 ; $i++) { 

          if(isset($days[$i]) && $days[$i] == $user_input_lower) {
            {
              {
              echo strtoupper($days[$i-1]) . "<br>";
              echo strtoupper($days[$i]) . "<br>";
              echo strtoupper($days[$i+1]) . "<br>";
              }
            }
        }
      }
        ?>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could add an if case.

```
if($i == 0)
    echo "SUNDAY";
else
    echo strtoupper($days[$i-1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add `if` before `echo`.

```
if($i>0){
    echo strtoupper($days[$i-1]) . "<br>";
} else {
    echo "Monday";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With date and time it's much easier to use PHP functions specifically developed for this and not to re-invent the wheel. Here is a simple example of using [`DateTime`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) object:

```
$now = new \DateTime('monday');

$next = clone $now;
$next->modify('+1 day');

$prev = clone $now;
$prev->modify('-1 day');

print $prev->format('l');  // "Sunday"
print $now->format('l');   // "Monday"
print $next->format('l');  // "Tuesday"
```

Alternatively your code may look like that:

```
$days = ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday'];
if (false !== $i = array_search('Monday', $days)) {
    print $i > 0 ? $days[$i-1] : $days[6];  // "Sunday"
    print $days[$i];                        // "Monday"
    print $i < 6 ? $days[$i+1] : $days[0];  // "Tuesday"
}
```

Both solutions will work correctly with "edge" days of week, i.e. "monday" and "sunday".